# Заливка областей на графике ZedGraph'a

Tags: c#, график, zedgraph

Мне надо на одной и той же области нарисовать линии графиков и некоторые области закрасить необходимым цветом. Для рисования графиков я использую ZedGraph. Есть ли возможность осуществить заливку в этом компоненте встроенными функциями? Если нет, то есть ли готовый компонент в котором это можно сделать не дорисовывая "ручками"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если под некоторыми областями вы имеете в виду области целиком лежащие под некоторыми графиками — просто используйте `Curve.Line.Fill`.

Если же нужно закрашивать *промежутки* лежащие под графиками, можно использовать не очень красивый, но простой в реализации способ: вне промежутка добавляйте график без заливки, а в промежутке — график того же цвета, но с заливкой.

На счёт совсем произвольных областей ничего кроме как написать на довольно-таки живой [форум самого проекта](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5431/A-flexible-charting-library-for-NET) посоветовать не могу.

Comment: Все оказалось гораздо проще:) Если нарисовать замкнутый контур, то заливается только он.

            PointPairList line = new PointPairList();
            line.Add(0, 50);
            line.Add(0, 100);
            line.Add(100, 100);
            line.Add(100, 50);
            line.Add(0, 50);
            var curve = graphPane.AddCurve("", line, Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 0));
            curve.Line.Fill = new Fill(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0), Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 0), 270F);